# Custom Field Search in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-fields

I am looking for a way to filter my posts by custom fields,
for example this link:

`mywebsite.com/?color:red`

looks for all the post that has custom field named `color` and the value `red`

I will be appreciate it if you can help me, I searched all over internet and I got nothing.

Comment: Are you using acf

Comment: Yes, but i don't think it has such a feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo but the example link you provided will not work. Query format is like this, ?property=value&another_property=another_value.

If your query is `mywebsite.com/?color=red` you can use the `$_GET` to get the value from the query and use it for what ever you need.

```
// check if we have a query property of color and that property has a value
if (isset($_GET['color']) && !empty($_GET['color'])) {
  // filter the result and remove any spaces
  $color = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'color', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

  // Create the arguments for the get_posts function
  $args = [
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // or how many you need
    'post_type'      => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE', // if the post type is 'post' you don't need this line
    'post_status'    => 'publish', // get only the published posts
    'meta_query'     => [ // Here we use our $_GET data to find all posts that have the value of red in a meta field named color
      [
        'key'     => 'color',
        'value'   => $color,
        'compare' => '='
      ]
    ]
  ];

  $posts = get_posts($args);
}

if (!empty($posts)) {
  // Now you can loop $posts and do what ever you want
}
```

Hope this helps =].

**EDIT**

Answering your question about getting posts with multiple meta values.

```
if ((isset($_GET['color']) && !empty($_GET['color'])) && (isset($_GET['size']) && !empty($_GET['size']))) {
// filter the result and remove any spaces
  $color = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'color', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
  $size  = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'size', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

// Create the arguments for the get_posts function
  $args = [
  'posts_per_page' => -1, // or how many you need
  'post_type'      => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE', // if the post type is 'post' you don't need this line
  'post_status'    => 'publish', // get only the published posts
  'meta_query' => [ // now we are using multiple meta querys, you can use as many as you want
      'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND" (taken from the wordpress codex)
      [
        'key'   => 'color',
        'value'   => $color,
        'compare' => '='
      ],
      [
        'key'     => 'size',
        'value'   => $size,
        'compare' => '='
      ]
    ]
  ];

  $posts = get_posts($args);
}

if (!empty($posts)) {
// Now you can loop $posts and do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it did exactly what i wanted it to do. thanks :)          but can you tell me how to combine the two properties together as you said: `mywebsite.com/?color=red&size=small`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACF-fields in a Meta Query like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'color',
    'meta_value'    => 'red'
));
```

There are more examples in the ACF documentation:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/#custom-field%20parameters

Comment: i'm aware of that, if i use it, i will have to create 30 or 40 different pages because there is about 10 different Custom Fields that i have for each post. i'm looking for some kind of a filter.